# Git repository on Microsoft Azure - is it possible to disconnect?

Tags: git, azure

Hi I have a website that I host on MS Azure at username.azurewebsites.net.

When I am in the editor mode at username.scm.azurewebsites.net/dev/wwwroot/
The Visual Studio Code clone that MS uses for editing files, always connected to MS Azure Git repository.

Any idea why? I am actually just publishing the web site from Visual Studio to Azure, but I am not using Azure for source code control.

Is it possible to disconnect MS Git? Should I disconnect?

Thanks.